# I can't run a Flutter project anymore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-test

Yesterday I worked the last time on my Flutter project. Today I only started Android Studio and I tried to launch my project, and I received an Error message. I tried everything and I checked also if there are some updates etc.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Here is the Error Message:

```
[+13326 ms] C:\Users\******\AndroidStudioProjects\PROJECTNAME\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
[   +1 ms]  uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\******\AndroidStudioProjects\PROJECTNAME\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
[        ]  Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
[        ]      or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
[        ]      or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
[        ] > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:audioplayers] C:\Users\******\AndroidStudioProjects\PROJECTNAME\build\audioplayers\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
[        ]      Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
[        ]          or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
[        ]          or use tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 13s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"ab743200-5f09-4853-ae95-0b0cb729d0f0","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[ +351 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:474:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [official document](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) carefully. As it mentioned, configure your `build.gradle` file with `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers"/>`.

> **Gradle Build Failing**
>
> In order to support the playBytes method, this has a hard requirement on using API >= 23 features, and your build may failure depending on your minimum sdk targeting. To override this, you will need to add < uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="xyz.luan.audioplayers"/> to your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

```
minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 23
```

one of the plugins (`xyz.luan.audioplayers`) you have used is incompatible with android versions below API23. You need to set your projects minimum SDK Version to 23 or Higher.

go to `android` folder in your project and open `app` folder then open `build.gradle` file.

in that file, under `defaultConfig` edit the following line as follows

```
minSdkVersion 23
```